# Use Forge Viewer SceneBuilder Extension to report an error "addMesh()" is not a function

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

I saw a case of using SceneBuilder Extension on Forge COMMUNITY BLOG [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/scenebuilder-extension-forge-viewer-action).

But when I tried to implement this case, I ran into a trouble.

I loaded [SimpleCustomGeometry Extension](https://sample-collection.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/js/extensions/SimpleCustomGeomExt.js) into my program. When I run the program, the following error occurred:
`Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): _this2.modelBuilder.addMesh is not a function`.
Can anyone help me? thank you very much!

Here are some of my operating environments:

- The version of `SceneBuilder Extension` is `LMV v7.3.0`
- The computer system used is Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code of the [SimpleCustomGeometryExt](https://sample-collection.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/js/extensions/SimpleCustomGeomExt.js) doesn't seem to contain any `_this2`. Have you modified the extension code in any way? I have just tried loading the extension in a simple Forge app myself, and there are no issues.

Also, feel free to check out this blog post to get more details and code snippets related to the `SceneBuilder` extension: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-models-forge-viewer.